# iPhone 4s Wi-Fi antenna

Tags: ios, wifi, iphone

I have an iPhone 4s (1 1/2 years old) and suddenly the Wi-Fi is acting strange.

The Wi-Fi won't connect to any network, when I open the Settings app to select a network it will either find no networks or the settings app will crash. A hardware reset (Homebutton + Powerbutton) will result in 2 scenarios:

1. The Wi-Fi is working again, but only for a certain amount of time until it occurs again.
2. The Wi-Fi is disabled and I cannot enable it again. The Wi-Fi icon in Command Center is **grayed out** and in the **Settings** I cannot change the slide.

Is the Wi-Fi antenna messed up? What can I try else?

Comment: Sounds like you need a visit to the Apple Store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing a hardware reset as you said in your question, I think there's no option left but a broken antenna.

It's worth visiting Apple OR even better a local repair-man because if you get it repaired at Apple you pay at least 2 times as much.

Since it's a 4s you could consider looking around for a good deal for a new 5 or even 5s.